# How to deploy artefacts to Artifactory using Maven without a POM

Tags: maven, metadata, artifactory

I need to send a jar file to artifactory maven repo. I don't want to use pom.xml. I have configured settings.xml with details of artifactory. What would be the full commandline command to send jar to artifactory. I need maven-matadata.xml to be generated so that with every upload I can fetch  tag in .xml file.

And also what would be default location of settings.xml? I see there are two locations. One is withing "apache-maven" folder and other one is inside .m2 folder under user's home directory.

Thank you

Comment: When I execute following, it throes me error that pom file is not found.

mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=https://my-artifactory.fkc.com/maven-prereleases -DrepositoryId= arti-mavenpre -Dfile=trial.zip -DgroupId=com/org/mydir -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=zip

I don't want to use pom. So executed above command.

Answer (score 0):

After using double quotes in mvn command (as I am executing it in powershell), it is working fine.